# how developers can troubleshoot issues/errors that occur in Production in minified bundle file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Currently whenever there is any unhandled error in UI, the stack trace of the error gets logged into the server logs.
we can see, the minified bundle file is one big file and not easy to understand. How can we simplify it so that it can be easily interpreted and used by developers to troubleshoot prod issues?

Comment: If you control the minification process, or have access to the library, there are usually [source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) that you can include in your production deployment that will help you debug.

Comment: We just point our dev environments to production, so we can run our unminified local setup with our prod servers

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, you can just use source maps. If they aren't available on the client because of security reasons, you could map the minified stack traces to your source code with a library like [retrace](https://github.com/fgnass/retrace). This tool essentially allows you to use source maps server side which in turn make the minified stack traces more readable.

[More info on retrace](https://github.com/fgnass/retrace/blob/master/README.md)

[Nice introductory article on source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)